# Apache Rewrite to add html extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get an apache RewriteRule to take a url and return the url + .html

Ex: 'www.domain.com/about' should serve the page 'www.domain.com/about.html'

I have tried numerous solutions from SO already but I believe there are some complications due to the site layout.

I am hosting on Network Solutions, so it's shared hosting, and this is a development site so I currently have the dev.domain.com pointed to /htdocs/dev

Directory Structure

```
-htdocs
--(contains existing sites files)
--.htaccess

----dev
------(contains dev site files)
------.htaccess
```

So as you can see there is an existing .htaccess file that maybe doing something and there maybe a subdomain issue, I'm not entirely sure, this is my first time working with Apache.

Here's my existing .htaccess which resides in the /htdocs/dev folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Yes I tried `RewriteBase /` to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You are instructing Apache to make a file check (`-f`), but it doesn't know where to look. Just change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.html -f [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f [NC]
```

That way Apache has a fully qualified path from your filesystem's root.

Comment: So I really thought that was going to work, and I had tried something to that effect earlier, but it is still giving me a `404`